# Replacing dot by *?

Tags: replacement, built-in-symbols

I am unable to replace dot by *.

```
Replace[a.a, .-> *]
```

Is there any solution to get this done?

Comment: `a.a /. Dot -> Times`?

Comment: Please read through this tutorial in full: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ExpressionsOverview.html and also check the `Replace` documentation (it operates at level 0 by default).  `Reaplce` effectively works on the `FullForm` of expressions, not code strings.

Comment: I voted to leave it open, as it is possible, that more people are confused about the same aspect @Szabolcs pointed out..

Comment: In Wolfram, the inner structure of an expression is highly possible not what it looks like. For using rules for substitution, `FullForm` is useful to check what an expression really is.

Comment: @Johu Could you include the links to the relevant tutorials, so this can be used as a target for duplicates in the future? It seemed to me that the main reason for the misunderstanding was not being aware of the expression structure ("full form"). The `Replace` thing is important to get it working, but it is really just a practical detail, not a conceptual point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`ReplaceAll (/.)`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html):

```
a.a /. Dot -> Times
```

> a^2

Alternatively, you can temporarily redefine `Dot` as `Times` using [`Block`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html):

```
Block[{Dot = Times}, a.a]
```

> a^2

Answer (score 7):

I think there are several reasonons pointed out by Szabolcs in the comments why the approach failed, and they are not all supper basic by my standard. I would like to point them out.

**First the basics**

[Everything is an expression.](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EverythingIsAnExpression.html)

`foo -> bar` is the same thing as `Rule[foo,bar]` and the same thing as `foo~Rule~bar`.

This underlying expression is often hidden and not important, but checking the underlying description is very helpful when debugging. Check out [`FullForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html) and [`TreeForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TreeForm.html).

**The second argument `.-> *` is not a valid syntax**

When parsing this input, the interpreter expects `.`, `->` and `*` to be infix operators. Having two or more infix operators next to each other can not be interpreted and it is indicated by codehighlighting of the cell:

[image]

It effectivly reads:

```
(~Dot~) (~ReplaceAll~) (~Times~)
```

which can not be interpreted, as left and right operands are missing.

Also `ToExpression[".->*"]` returns a message

> ToExpression::sntx: Invalid syntax in or before `".->*"`.

**Repalce checks only the top level**

Repalce will not replace *a part* of an expression. Compare:

```
In[1953]:= 
Replace[Dot, Dot -> Times]
Replace[Dot[a.a], Dot -> Times]
Replace[Dot[a.a], Dot[a.a] -> Times[a a]]

Out[1953]= Times

Out[1954]= a.a

Out[1955]= a^2
```

**Working solutions**

Either use more general replacement rule:

```
In[1939]:= Replace[a.b, (f_).(g_) :> (f*g)]

Out[1939]= a b
```

or instead of `Replace` use a `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) , which tries to apply the pattern also to subexpressions:

```
In[1943]:= 
FullForm[a.b]
ReplaceAll[a.b, Dot -> Times]
FullForm[%]

Out[1943]//FullForm= 
Dot[a,b]

Out[1944]= 
a b

Out[1950]//FullForm=
Times[a, b]
```